# highlight currently selected link in css menu bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, menu

I have a page with this URL: http://localhost:8000/progress/c/?l=1&c=1

And the below content to work as a simple css menu bar.

```
<div class="menu_div">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/progress/c/?l=1&c=1"> l1c1 </a></li>
        <li><a href="/progress/c/?l=2&c=1"> l1c1 </a></li>
        <li><a href="/progress/c/?l=3&c=1"> l1c1 </a></li>
        <li><a href="/progress/c/?l=4&c=1"> l1c1 </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS styling is

```
.menu_div ul
{
    padding:6px;
    margin:0px;
    font-size:12px;
    list-style:none;
    text-indent:15px;

}
.menu_div ul li
{
    line-height:28px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
.menu_div ul li a
{
    text-decoration:none;
    font-color:#3A332D;
    display:block;
}
.menu_div ul li a:hover
{
    background:blue;
}
.menu_div ul li#active
{
    background:blue;
}
```

When I hover over the links the background color changes but the currently selected menu link is not highlighted in blue.

I'm using django framework.

Comment: I believe your `localhost` URL is not accessible for the rest of the world ;)

Comment: @VisioN if you read the question, that's besides the point.

Comment: @sg3s, yes but how can you know what `active` does the author mean. We do not have enough HTML for that. If 'currently selected menu link' comes with class `active` the answer is obvious, otherwise there might be other issues.

Comment: @VisioN fair enough, more html or direct access to the source always helps

Answer (score 5):

Try this jQuery code, it will add the class automatically

```
$(function(){

    var url = window.location.href; 

    $("#menu a").each(function() {

        if(url == (this.href)) { 
            $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you, Thilanka De Silva. Ridiculously simple solution and the best part is it works. I tried every single trick known to me, googled, tried accepted Answers on SOF but this gem tucked away did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

In your CSS you have a class with the id 'active', this should probably be a class like this:

```
.menu_div ul li.active
{
    background:blue;
}
```

Further, I wouldn't recommend trying to match the 'active' or better formulated 'current' page using javascript client side.

Instead your script on the server should recognize the current page and add a class to the related menu item so it would look like this:

```
<li class="active"><a href="/progress/c/?l=1&c=1"> l1c1 </a></li>
```

Comment: thanks. i was thinking of adding that feature using javascript. But since you don't recommend it, i have to find a way to do that in django

Comment: @John Unfortunately I am not too familiar with django but a simple search led me to this page which might be useful: http://gnuvince.wordpress.com/2007/09/14/a-django-template-tag-for-the-current-active-page/

Comment: one more problem. the bullets appear for my ul list. Is there a way to make it disappear.

Comment: @John Sure, use `list-style: none;` on the unordered list (`ul`)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your id `#active` to class `.active` - that is more right way:

```
.menu_div ul li.active
{
    background:blue;
}
```

and add this class to active element in your list:

```
<div class="menu_div">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="/progress/c/?l=1&c=1"> l1c1 </a></li>
        <li><a href="/progress/c/?l=2&c=1"> l1c1 </a></li>
        <li><a href="/progress/c/?l=3&c=1"> l1c1 </a></li>
        <li><a href="/progress/c/?l=4&c=1"> l1c1 </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu_div ul li#active
```

It says the active link needs an id of active. I see no id, hence why it is not blue.

If you want the link to be active, you are going to have to set the item to be active, the browser will not do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just

**css**

```
.menu_div ul li.active{background:blue}
```

**html**

```
<div class="menu_div">
    <ul>
        <li id="page1"><a href="/progress/c/?l=1&c=1"> l1c1 </a></li>
        <li id="page2"><a href="/progress/c/?l=2&c=1"> l1c1 </a></li>
        <li id="page3"><a href="/progress/c/?l=3&c=1"> l1c1 </a></li>
        <li id="page4"><a href="/progress/c/?l=4&c=1"> l1c1 </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**script**

```
#In every page just put this script and change the id
<script>$("#page1").addClass('active');</script>
```